# Is there a simpler way to calculate mean while dropping negative values?

Tags: r, dplyr

What I'm trying to do is calculate the mean of the three values, excluding any negative values. Maybe there's a simpler way to do it?

```
#repro eg.
df1 <- structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.0867, 0.13, 0.195, 0.293, 
                                 0.439, 0.658, 0.988, 1.481, 2.222, 3.333, 5), Replicate = c(1.44558642857143, 
                                                                                             1.15371058441558, 1.02689350649351, 0.868325194805193, 0.677496493506493, 
                                                                                             0.526922597402598, 0.371443376623376, 0.252155129870129, 0.183662272727273, 
                                                                                             0.122282922077922, 0.0892741558441554, 0.0637236363636363), Replicate.1 = c(1.41649441558442, 
                                                                                                                                                                         1.11617954545455, 1.00826512987013, 0.851684350649351, 0.677447077922078, 
                                                                                                                                                                         0.523192987012987, 0.368280584415585, 0.262413311688312, 0.175215584415585, 
                                                                                                                                                                         0.129054415584416, 0.092797987012987, 0.0627326623376624), Replicate.2 = c(1.35938512987013, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1.21117383116883, 1.01522181818182, 0.891895324675324, 0.695687207792208, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.518078831168831, 0.361077272727272, 0.25113487012987, 0.167685064935065, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.121838701298701, 0.0813138961038961, 0.0731186363636365)), class = c("rowwise_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("concentration", "Replicate", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "Replicate.1", "Replicate.2"), row.names = c(NA, 12L))
docv <- function(df1){
  df1 %>% rename(Replicate.1=Replicate,Replicate.2=Replicate.1,Replicate.3=Replicate.2) %>% 
    mutate(tnegcount=sum(c(Replicate.1<0,Replicate.2<0,Replicate.3<0))) %>%
    mutate(averagev=case_when(tnegcount==0 ~ mean(c(Replicate.1,Replicate.2,Replicate.3)),
                              tnegcount>0 ~ c(Replicate.1,Replicate.2,Replicate.3)[c(Replicate.1,Replicate.2,Replicate.3)>0] %>% mean()
    )) %>% return()
}

docv(df1)
```

Comment: You're confusing the interfaces of `sum` and `mean`. If you give `sum` three separate vectors, it will add up everything in all three. The first argument to `mean` is not `...`, but just `x`, so it is expect a single, concatenated vector.

Comment: Food for thought: you could also achieve row-wise means by using base R: `df1$Means <- rowMeans(df1[, 2:4])`

Comment: 1) Do you really need `rename` in the function? 2) Without renaming the columns, `case_when(tnegcount == 0 ~ mean(c(Replicate, Replicate.1, Replicate.2)),`

Comment: Thanks, I need the rename for my sanity and the output requires those names. Thanks for the comments on the mean() function. I fixed it.

Comment: You have no negative values in this sample data, do you think it would be helpful to have data that supports your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R you could do:

```
df1 = structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.0867, 0.13, 0.195, 0.293, 0.439, 0.658, 0.988, 1.481, 2.222, 3.333, 5), 
                 Replicate = c(-0.4689826737158, -0.25575220072642, 0.145706726703793, 0.816415579989552, -0.596636137925088, 0.796779369935393, 0.889350537210703, 0.321595584973693, 0.258228087797761, -0.876427459064871, -0.588050850201398, -0.646886494942009), 
                 Replicate.1 = c(0.374045693315566, -0.231792563572526, 0.539682839997113, -0.00460151582956314, 0.435237016528845, 0.983812189660966, -0.239929641131312, 0.554890442639589, 0.869410462211818, -0.575714957434684, 0.303347532171756, -0.748889808077365), 
                 Replicate.2 = c(-0.465558662544936, -0.227771814912558, -0.973219333682209, -0.235224085859954, 0.73938169144094, -0.319302006624639, -0.0358397690579295, 0.199131650850177, -0.0129173859022558, -0.627564797177911, 0.654746637213975, 0.336933476384729)),
            .Names = c("concentration", "Replicate", "Replicate.1", "Replicate.2"), 
            row.names = c(NA, 12L), 
            class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df1$averageV = apply(df1[,2:4], 1, function(x){mean(x[x>0])})
```

This gives the following result:

```
   concentration  Replicate  Replicate.1 Replicate.2  averageV
1         0.0000 -0.4689827  0.374045693 -0.46555866 0.3740457
2         0.0867 -0.2557522 -0.231792564 -0.22777181       NaN
3         0.1300  0.1457067  0.539682840 -0.97321933 0.3426948
4         0.1950  0.8164156 -0.004601516 -0.23522409 0.8164156
5         0.2930 -0.5966361  0.435237017  0.73938169 0.5873094
6         0.4390  0.7967794  0.983812190 -0.31930201 0.8902958
7         0.6580  0.8893505 -0.239929641 -0.03583977 0.8893505
8         0.9880  0.3215956  0.554890443  0.19913165 0.3585392
9         1.4810  0.2582281  0.869410462 -0.01291739 0.5638193
10        2.2220 -0.8764275 -0.575714957 -0.62756480       NaN
11        3.3330 -0.5880509  0.303347532  0.65474664 0.4790471
12        5.0000 -0.6468865 -0.748889808  0.33693348 0.3369335
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm changing your data in three ways:

- I'm removing the `rowwise` class on it;
- I'm introducing some negative values to test your question; and
- I'm adding a `rowid` field in order to get the summary data back to the main column. (This column can be removed after the join without problem. If your real data has a true "id" field built-in, feel free to use that instead.)

The reason I'm choosing a reshape/join/reshape method is in case you ever have other than exactly 3 columns. Also, I'm not dealing with the renaming here, it's easy enough to do this after the pipe.

```
df1 %>%
  tidyr::gather(repl, v, -rowid, -concentration) %>%
  filter(v > 0) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarize(mu = mean(v, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  left_join(df1, ., by = "rowid")
# # A tibble: 12 x 6
#    concentration Replicate Replicate.1 Replicate.2 rowid      mu
#            <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#  1        0         1.45       -1.42        1.36       1  1.40  
#  2        0.0867    1.15       -1.12       -1.21       2  1.15  
#  3        0.13      1.03        1.01        1.02       3  1.02  
#  4        0.195     0.868       0.852       0.892      4  0.871 
#  5        0.293     0.677       0.677       0.696      5  0.684 
#  6        0.439     0.527       0.523       0.518      6  0.523 
#  7        0.658     0.371       0.368       0.361      7  0.367 
#  8        0.988     0.252       0.262       0.251      8  0.255 
#  9        1.48      0.184       0.175       0.168      9  0.176 
# 10        2.22      0.122       0.129       0.122     10  0.124 
# 11        3.33      0.0893      0.0928      0.0813    11  0.0878
# 12        5        -0.0637     -0.0627     -0.0731    12 NA
```

---

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.0867, 0.13, 0.195, 0.293, 0.439, 0.658, 0.988, 1.481, 2.222, 3.333, 5),
                      Replicate = c(1.44558642857143, 1.15371058441558, 1.02689350649351, 0.868325194805193, 0.677496493506493, 0.526922597402598, 0.371443376623376, 0.252155129870129, 0.183662272727273, 0.122282922077922, 0.0892741558441554, -0.0637236363636363),
                      Replicate.1 = c(-1.41649441558442, -1.11617954545455, 1.00826512987013, 0.851684350649351, 0.677447077922078, 0.523192987012987, 0.368280584415585, 0.262413311688312, 0.175215584415585, 0.129054415584416, 0.092797987012987, -0.0627326623376624),
                      Replicate.2 = c(1.35938512987013, -1.21117383116883, 1.01522181818182, 0.891895324675324, 0.695687207792208, 0.518078831168831, 0.361077272727272, 0.25113487012987, 0.167685064935065, 0.121838701298701, 0.0813138961038961, -0.0731186363636365)),
                 class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
                 .Names = c("concentration", "Replicate", "Replicate.1", "Replicate.2"),
                 row.names = c(NA, 12L))


df1 <- ungroup(df1) %>% mutate(rowid = row_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat more complicated version, but provides some further generalization:

1. You can have more than 1 reference column.
2. You can have any number of columns to take the mean from.
3. You can specify the names of the new columns that are added.
4. You can optionally rename the columns that are used in taking the mean.

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.0867, 0.13, 0.195, 0.293, 0.439, 0.658, 0.988, 1.481, 2.222, 3.333, 5), 
                      Replicate.1 = c(1.44558642857143, 1.15371058441558, 1.02689350649351, 0.868325194805193, 
                                    0.677496493506493, 0.526922597402598, 0.371443376623376, 0.252155129870129, 
                                    0.183662272727273, 0.122282922077922, 0.0892741558441554, 0.0637236363636363), 
                      Replicate.2 = c(1.41649441558442, 1.11617954545455, 1.00826512987013, 0.851684350649351,
                                      0.677447077922078, 0.523192987012987, 0.368280584415585, 0.262413311688312, 
                                      0.175215584415585, 0.129054415584416, 0.092797987012987, 0.0627326623376624), 
                      Replicate.3 = c(1.35938512987013, 1.21117383116883, 1.01522181818182, 0.891895324675324, 
                                      0.695687207792208, 0.518078831168831, 0.361077272727272, 0.25113487012987, 
                                      0.167685064935065, 0.121838701298701, 0.0813138961038961, 0.0731186363636365)), 
                 class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 .Names = c("concentration", "Replicate", "Replicate.1", "Replicate.2"), row.names = c(NA, 12L))

### Add negative rows
extraRows_v <- rbind(c(5.1, -1, 5, 10), c(5.5, -3, -5, -2), c(6, 4, 3, -8))
colnames(extraRows_v) <- colnames(df1)
df2 <- rbind(df1, extraRows_v)

### Add extra reference column
random_v <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 5)
df3 <- cbind("Random" = random_v, df2)
```

Function:

```
meanPosOnly <- function(data, refCol_v, calcCol_v = NA, negCountName_v = "tnegcount", meanName_v = "averagev", rename_v = T) {
  #' Calculate means of positive values
  #' @description Calculate the mean value of all positive values in all rows of a data.frame, matrix, etc.
  #' @param data - data.frame, matrix, etc. Table of values
  #' @param refCol_v - character vector - Name of column(s) that will not be used in taking the mean. 
  #' Some sort of reference/metadata column(s). Must be before other columns.
  #' @param calcCol_v - vector (character or numeric) - 
  #' character - Name of column(s) that will be used in taking the mean. Default is NA, which will use all columns not in refCol_v.
  #' numeric - column indices of column(s) that will be used in taking the mean. 
  #' @param negCountName_v - character vector - name of column that will tally number of negative values in each row
  #' @param meanName_v - character vector - name of column that will contain the resulting average of all positive values in each row
  #' @param rename_v - logical - rename the calc columns by adding ".[0-9]" where [0-9] is 1 more than currently in name
  #' @value data.frame of same dimensions as data, with 2 extra columns denoting the number of negatives in each row and the mean of all positive values.
  #' @export

  ## Get column indices
  if (is.na(calcCol_v[1])) {
    cols_v <- grep(paste(refCol_v, collapse = "|"), colnames(data), invert = T)
  } else if (is.character(calcCol_v)) {
    cols_v <- which(colnames(data) %in% calcCol_v)
  } else {
    cols_v <- calcCol_v
  } # fi

  ## Get numeric columns
  whichNum_v <- which(sapply(data, class) == "numeric")

  ## Get result
  out_df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(data, 1, function(x) {
    whichMean_v <- which(as.numeric(x[cols_v]) >= 0)
    num0_v <- length(cols_v) - length(whichMean_v)
    y <- mean(as.numeric(x[cols_v][whichMean_v]))
    z <- c(x, num0_v, y)
    return(z)
  })))

  ## Add names
  colnames(out_df)[c(ncol(out_df)-1,ncol(out_df))] <- c(negCountName_v, meanName_v)

  ## Fix numeric columns
  for (c_v in c(whichNum_v, ncol(out_df)-1, ncol(out_df))) out_df[,c_v] <- as.numeric(as.character(out_df[,c_v]))

  ## Fix calc names
  colNames_v <- colnames(out_df)[cols_v]
  if (rename_v) {
    colNames_v <- sapply(colNames_v, function(x) {
      y <- strsplit(x, split = "\\.")[[1]]
      z <- ifelse(is.na(y[2]),
                  paste0(y, ".1"),
                  paste0(y[1], ".", (as.numeric(y[2])+1)))
      return(z)})
  } # fi
  colnames(out_df)[cols_v] <- colNames_v

  ## Return
  return(out_df)
} # meanPosOnly
```

Usage:

```
### Standard
meanPosOnly(df1, refCol_v = "concentration")
meanPosOnly(df2, refCol_v = "concentration")

### Only 2 columns
meanPosOnly(df1, refCol_v = "concentration", calcCol_v = c("Replicate.1", "Replicate.2"))
meanPosOnly(df2, refCol_v = "concentration", calcCol_v = c("Replicate.1", "Replicate.2"))

### No rename
meanPosOnly(df2, refCol_v = "concentration", rename_v = F)

### 2 columns, no rename
meanPosOnly(df2, refCol_v = "concentration", calcCol_v = c(3,4), rename_v = F)

### Extra reference column
meanPosOnly(df3, refCol_v = c("concentration", "Random"))
```